UIAutomator2 keeps crashing with 255 code when used with appium
I am trying to run automation using appium and android emulators. But the UiAutomator2 keeps crashing every few instructions with exit code 255.
[Instrumentation] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 255, signal null
I am using the emulator with API 35 and the latest version of appium. I can't even figure out how to debug this issue. I have tried enabling debug logs on appium. And can't seem to figure out how to find the error in adb logcat as well.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Try installing the UiAutomator2 driver:
appium driver install uiautomator2

This also needs to be defined in the capabilities:
"automationName": "UiAutomator2"


Set up Android automation requirements

